# React Native Android: Generating Signed APK through Android Studio doesn't include JS Bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, reactjs, react-native

Generating Signed APK through Android Studio doesn't include JS Bundle.
I have been struggling install the release build on device it was not working. finally i enabled the debugging for Release build and i find out that Generated signed apk through android studio doesn't include js bundle.

How can i generate a signed apk including js bundle? to upload to play store.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the steps here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html?

Comment: @tegon Yeah I have tried that. but see the results : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057231/react-native-android-generating-signed-apk-through-android-studio-doesnt-inclu

Comment: What do you mean? You linked to the same question

Comment: I usually generate mine apps following the docs (with the command line, not through android studio). Which RN version are you using?

Comment: @tegon Its rn 0.38. see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057036/react-native-android-debug-works-perfect-release-doesnt

Comment: From RN 0.57, follow https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it on RN documentations :

> Creating a release build in Android Studio You can use Android Studio
>   to create your release builds too! It’s as easy as creating release
>   builds of your previously-existing native Android app. There’s just
>   one additional step, which you’ll have to do before every release
>   build. You need to execute the following to create a React Native
>   bundle, which’ll be included with your native Android app:

```js
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/com/your-company-name/app-package-name/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/com/your-company-name/app-package-name/src/main/res/
```

> Now just create a release build of your native app from within Android
>   Studio as usual and you should be good to go!