# React Native Android Released Version works like Debug Version

Tags: react-native

I build React Native Released Version and publish it Google Play Store.
But it doesn't work.

Do not move to next HomeScreen from SplashScreen.
So I test with My Android Emulator and suddenly Meteor JS Bundle Run on Terminal and works like Debug version.

Similiar with this bug
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16793

But solution of this link doesn't work for me.
The solution is to remove "`import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;`" line, but I don't have.

This is the code of MainApplication

```
package org.sharingappforstudent;

import android.app.Application;

import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
import org.wonday.pdf.RCTPdfView;
import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
import cl.json.RNSharePackage;
import com.reactlibrary.RNMailCorePackage;
import com.magus.fblogin.FacebookLoginPackage;

import com.reactnative.ivpusic.imagepicker.PickerPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.storage.RNFirebaseStoragePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.database.RNFirebaseDatabasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
import com.AlexanderZaytsev.RNI18n.RNI18nPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new SplashScreenReactPackage(),
        new RCTPdfView(),
        new RNFetchBlobPackage(),
        new RNSharePackage(),
        new RNMailCorePackage(),
        new FacebookLoginPackage(),
        new PickerPackage(),
        new VectorIconsPackage(),
        new ImagePickerPackage(),
        new RNFirebasePackage(),
        new RNI18nPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseStoragePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
        new RNFirebaseDatabasePackage(),
        new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
        new MapsPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.sharingappforstudent"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.3"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    // (!!!ATTENTION!!!) FIX FOR MAIL CORE DEPENDENCIES (!!!DO NOT REMOVE!!!)
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libgnustl_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-pdf')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile(project(':react-native-mailcore'))
    compile project(':react-native-facebook-login')
    compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile (project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }

    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" // From node_modules
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0"

    compile project(':react-native-facebook-login')

    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    // Firebase dependencies
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0"
    compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar"
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Need help.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your MainApplication.java, I have also just recently experienced this issue and the solution to remove the 'import' worked for me. What command are you using to build the release version?

Comment: @mjabadilla  I updated my problem.

Comment: I don't see any issues on the MainApplication. I would try to cleanup all the cache and existing build first by running `cd android && ./gradlew clean`. Can you show your `app/build.gradle`? I'm curious if you have the correct release config in there

Comment: @mjabadilla I attached

Comment: Did you try `cd android && ./gradlew clean` and `react-native run-android --variant=release`?

Comment: I don't well about make release using terminal. I always build release version with Android Studio

Comment: There are additional steps do if building release apks thru Android Studio as explain here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41098833/1405577 otherwise. I would recommend to use the command line. The `--variant=release` is very helpful when you have several conf. (i.e. staging, test) configs. As per, the commands try the command line and the link I provided first before we continue looking for other solutions. Another command is `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` if you don't want to have the app running after build

Comment: @mjabadilla, it works fine. thanks.